# Menu did'nt show from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i try to get list from table, i code this on controller

```
var _menu = new List<MenuModel>();
            try
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                string query = "";
                var role = Session["sessionrole"];

                query = "SELECT * FROM \"SubMenu\" INNER JOIN \"Main_menu\" ON \"SubMenu\".\"MainMenuId\" = \"Main_menu\".\"Id\"  WHERE \"ROLE_ID\" = @role";

                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);


                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    _menu.Add(item: new MenuModel
                    {
                        MainMenuName = reader["MainMenu"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)reader["MainMenu"] : ""

                    });
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            Session["Menu"] = _menu;
```

i added _menuPartial in shared to rendered in view index

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu Example</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @if (Session["Menu"] != null)
            {

                var MenuMaster = (List<Accountstatement.Models.MenuModel>)Session["Menu"];
                var groupByMenu = MenuMaster.GroupBy(x => x.MainMenuName).ToList();

                foreach (var MenuList in groupByMenu)
                {

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">@MenuList.Key<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            @foreach (var SubMenuList in MenuList)
                            {
                                <li><a href="#">@SubMenuList.SubMenuName</a></li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                }
            }

        </ul>
```

the table i try to input is :
MainMenu
| Id       | MainMenu       |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | Konven         |
| 2        | Syari          |
Id is varchar MainMenu is varchar

i try add dynamic menu from database to add menu in view index and i don't see my list rendered, any recommendation?

Comment: Calling `ToString` on a `List<T>` will not do anything useful.  You need to do something to extract the values of the list like `string.Join(", ", list.Select(x => ExtractMeaningfulString(x))`

Comment: As Juharr mentioned outcome of `Session["Menu"].ToString()` will be `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Accountstatement.Models.MenuModel]`. There can be multiple items in the list, how do you want them to be displayed?

Comment: Aside: you should not be caching the connection object. All SQL objects such as connections and adapters should be disposed wit `using` blocks. And an empty `catch` block will just swallow all exceptions

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i want to render all the multiple item list

Comment: @juhar i try to extract value of the list but it still doesn't show the list